# Create workers for repeatable cycle Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, concurrency

How I could use workers (multi processing) when for example I could use 10 at one time at most but I need them to do ~ 150 tasks.

```
def main():
    for i in serverinfo :
        grabfile(i,serverinfo[i]["ip"],serverinfo[i]["psw"])
```

`grabfile` is task which I want to do with those ~10 workers, but I really don't understand how to make them work together that for example they all starter from task numbers 1-10 and then when they done they would get new tasks to do tasks 11-20 P.S. I refer task number as **"i"** in code snipet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ThreadPoolExecuter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) from [cuncurrnt.futures](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html)

It should look something like this:

```
import concurrent.futures

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10) # max 10 worker threads

for x in data_to_work_on:
    pool.submit(worker_function, x.param1, x.param2)
```

Comment: so in this example for cycle would me my original cycle just on "worker function" I would use grabfile() and params which grab function requires, am I right ?

Comment: Yes. but you will have to pass the function's name `grabfile` not make a call to that function `grabfile()` ie: `pool.submit(grabfile, i, serverinfo[i]["ip"], serverinfo[i]["psw"])`

Comment: ok I get it now just you should submit `pool.submit(grabfile( i, serverinfo[i]["ip"], serverinfo[i]["psw"]))` . By the way It wont matter if one worker finish faster then another it still gonna wait for another ones ?

Comment: When a worker finishes, another worker thread will be started to work on one of the remaining submissions.

Comment: but that sounds like simple cycle if second worker waits for first one

Comment: No, first 10 workers run concurrently. When one of them finishes the 11th worker starts running.

Comment: I tried to make multiple ftplib connections with this, but it seems you can't have more then one ftp connection at once